# I cant access the slot inside a shadow dom CSS

Tags: dom, shadow, slot

I must access the slot of an ionic page to insert the 'background: inherit' on it. I tried everything and still I cant access it via CSS.[I must access this slot tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2tis.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access (select via CSS rules) elements that are part of shadow DOM - that is by design. You can read more here: https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/

You have options:

1. Either the element you need to change exposes CSS variable that you can access and modify
2. You might re-write component / make your own
3. You can try and "hack" it using a directive that adds another "style" element to the shadow dom: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-shadow-dom/137350/3

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My only problem is that the only place that the blur works for me is at <slot></slot> that is auto generate. I will try to make my own component but it is a long way to me.

Comment: If you can create a new question and describe specifically what is the issue (with blur) and what you are trying to achieve - maybe you will avoid writing your component? maybe there is a better solution?